# Proof of Commutativity of a Diagonal Matrix to a Power

Tags: matrices

Good afternoon everyone, I have a question for one of my university courses. The question is:

Show that if $D$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative elements, then $AD^P=D^PA$ is and only if $AD=DA$

I would like to prove this using induction, so I start with $P=1$

$$AD^1=D^1A$$

From the question

Next I wish to show this is true for $P=l+1$

I start by writing out the matrix multiplication in index notation because I would like to show they are equal:

$$[AD^{l+1}]_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{a_{ik}d_{kj}^{l+1}}$$
$$[AD^{l+1}]_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{d_{ik}^{l+1}a_{kj}}$$

This is where I get confused. I know since $D$ is a diagonal matrix, $D$ is only nonzero if $i=j$. I believe that I can then rewrite my index notation sums as follows, however I do not know if this is correct:

$$[AD^{l+1}]_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{a_{ik}d_{kk}^{l+1}}$$
$$[D^{l+1}A]_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{d_{kk}^{l+1}a_{kj}}$$

My next question is if this is correct, can I assume $a_{ik}=a_{kj}$ since:

$$[AD]_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{a_{ik}d_{kj}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{d_{ik}a_{kj}}=[DA]_{ij}$$

I'm somewhat unsure as this seems like it isn't very clear.

The only other way I could think of solving this is if I assume $A$ is also a diagonal matrix since $AD=DA$ is true is both $A$ and $D$ are diagonal matrices.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can shorten this quite a lot using strong induction: If $AD^k = D^k A$, then $AD^{k + 1} = ADD^k = DAD^k = DD^k A = D^{k + 1} A$.

Comment: Hmm. Does it seem like this solution proves a much more general theorem?  In any ring, $a d^k = d^k a $ for all $k>0$ if and only if $ad = da$.